# how to set custom value to CellRangeAddress[]

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi

Can we add `CellRangeAddress[]` But using it As like this :

```
$P$32:$P$38,$P$43:$P$45,$P$50:$P$76,$P$81:$P$116,$P$121:$P$121,$P$126:$P$130
```

so Instead of give it a value Like This :

```
CellRangeAddress[] my_data_range = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("P32:P130")};
```

i have String contine the same range but with , between thiam so it likes more then one range.

The output of Excel Should be like this :

[image]

I opened the .zip file of the .xlsx file and had a look at the Sheet.xml >> i fond it like this :

```
<conditionalFormatting sqref="P26 P45:P58 P28:P40 P63:P73 P78:P266">
    <cfRule type="iconSet" priority="89">
        <iconSet iconSet="3Flags">
            <cfvo type="num" val="$L$274" />
            <cfvo type="num" val="$L$274" />
            <cfvo type="num" val="$L$273" />
        </iconSet>
    </cfRule>
</conditionalFormatting>
```

it is located in this line : `sqref="P26 P45:P58 P28:P40 P63:P73 P78:P266">`

but how we can do it in java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CellRangeAddress[]` is an array of `CellRangeAddress`es. So there is no need to set only one array item. There can be multiple items also.

```
  //CellRangeAddress[] my_data_range = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("P32:P130")};
  CellRangeAddress[] my_data_range = new CellRangeAddress[]{
      CellRangeAddress.valueOf("P32:P38"),
      CellRangeAddress.valueOf("P43:P45"),
      CellRangeAddress.valueOf("P50:P76"),
      CellRangeAddress.valueOf("P81:P116"),
      CellRangeAddress.valueOf("P121:P121"),
      CellRangeAddress.valueOf("P126:P130")      
  };
```

Comment: -1 for adding java tag And I want the code in Java at all ! Axel Richter Thanks for the correct answer And (shihabudheenk) Pls. Cry for the points !